# Vanishing points are collinear

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, computer-vision, cross-ratio

I am studying projective geometry where I came across a definition of **vanishing line**, "The line containing the vanishing point of 2 or more sets of parallel lines on a plane form the vanishing line".

I maybe missing some key concept to answer this but how do I prove that the vanishing points obtained are always collinear and thus form a vanishing point?

Comment: What kind of definitions do you start from? Do you have coordinates? Axioms? The answer depends a lot on what definitions you already have for “vanishing point” and “collinear”.

Comment: Since you called this a definition, is that the assumption of the theory that they are using? $\quad$ (Depending on how much you know / what your theory is) Alternatively, given any 3 sets of parallel lines, can you use Pascal's theorem to get that their respective vanishing points lie on the same line?

Comment: Maybe I needed to search a bit more for this when I had asked the question. This question has already been answered as per my requirement in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616044/prove-that-the-vanishing-line-can-be-determined-given-three-coplanar-equally-spa?rq=1.

Thanks MvG and Calvin